# Python: Passing function arguments through multiple dict

Tags: python

I am trying to create a URL through a function which allows me to pass multiple arguments as a dict and create the final URL

An example of API URL(**multiple filters can be passed)

```
https://myapi.com/api/trialdata/Master?filters=[{"type" : "Country", "Entry":["CAN","USA","NLD"]},{"type" : "Category", "Entry":["Fuel"]},{"type" : "Company", "Entry":["Shell"]}......]
```

How I'd like to pass arguments(**with curly brackets):

```
get_url(Master,{Country:CAN,NLD,USA},{Category:Fuel},{Company:Shell,..,..})
```

My code

```
def get_url(val_name,*argv):
    params=[]
    for param in argv:
        params.append(param)
    try:
        var_att=str(params[0])
        values=params[1::]
        my_lst_str = '","'.join(map(str, values))
        var_values= '"'+my_lst_str+'"'
        url='''https://myapi.com/api/trialdata/'''+str(val_name)+'''?filters=[{"AttributeName" : "'''+var_att+'''", "Values":['''+var_values+''']}]&size=100'''
    except:
        url = "https://myapi.com/api/trialdata/Master/{}?size=100".format(val_name)

    return url
```

This is how I pass arguments in my code

```
print(get_url("Master","Country",*["CAN","USA"...]))

<output>  https://myapi.com/api/trialdata/Master?filters=[{"type" : "Country", "Entry":["CAN","USA","NLD"]}]&size=100
```

As you can see my code is very limited and unable to pass more than one filter pair(if I can call it that). The format too is quite constrained

Requesting experts on the forum to share possible solutions/examples.

Comment: What is preventing you from modifying your code to use the desired argument format?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your API expects a JSON value; you should use the `json` module to construct it.

Comment: @ScottHunter  I'm not able to figure out how to add more [type-entry] filter pairs dynamically without hard coding them in URL

Comment: Beware : putting non-URL-encoded strings into URLs may not work if your data contains special characters. See [urllib.quote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote)